# extract the dress from image with python

Tags: python, image, opencv, numpy, crop

I was doing some research about how can i crop the dress in this image (see image1) using python and some other libraries, so i need to do this for different images with many models on the photo, they will have different sizes and shapes so i need to do something generic that could take the image, analize it and remove all but the dress,

image1 
[image: This is an example image before processing]
I have a code that takes this image and do some mask around the model's shape and put the alpha channel so i get this (image2):

image2
[image: image after processing]

As you can see this is the result of my code, but is not what i need, i really need to remove all the colors around the model, if possible all the colors around the dress, and need to be generic.. i.e. should work with different models that have different shapes and sizes

this is the code i have written on python using PIL and numpy libraries, i was using python 3.4

```
    import numpy
from numpy import array
from PIL import Image
#import cv2

# read image as RGB and add alpha (transparency)
im = Image.open("one.jpg").convert("RGBA")

# convert to numpy (for convenience)
imArray = numpy.asarray(im)

# create mask (zeros + circle with ones)

center = (100,100)
radius = 100
mask = numpy.zeros((imArray.shape[0],imArray.shape[1]))
for i in range(imArray.shape[0]):
    for j in range(imArray.shape[1]):
        #if (i-center[0])**2 + (j-center[0])**2 < radius**2:
        #    mask[i,j] = 1
        if ((j > 110 and j<240 and i>65 ) or (j > 440 and j<580 and i>83 )):
            mask[i, j] = 1

"""
lower = numpy.array([0,0,0])
upper = numpy.array([15, 15, 15])
shapeMask = cv2.inRange(imArray, lower, upper)
"""

# assemble new image (uint8: 0-255)
newImArray = numpy.empty(imArray.shape,dtype='uint8')

# colors (three first columns, RGB)
newImArray[:,:,:3] = imArray[:,:,:3]

# transparency (4th column)
newImArray[:,:,3] = mask*255          

# back to Image from numpy
newIm = Image.fromarray(newImArray, "RGBA")
newIm.save("one2.png")
```

The result should be a PNG image with all transparent except the model, or the dress if possible

As you can see im only making a static mask that always will be in the same place, and it is rectangular, not adjusted to the model, let me know if you need  more explanation of what i need

Thanks a lot!
cesar

Comment: Is the background always the same? Because probably the easiest way would be to filter out those white and blue colors.

Comment: The background could change

Comment: Is the background uniform, like 2 colors as in this case or may it be colorful?

Comment: simple background, not with landscape or something with too much colors

Answer (score 2):

This is a very hard problem, especially when you do not know what the background is going to be and when the background has shadows.

The netting of the dress is also going to be lost in part or whole as might the areas between the body and the arms.

Here is an attempt using ImageMagick. But OpenCV has similar commands.

Input:

[image]

First, blur the image slightly and then extract the Hue channel from HCL colorspace.

Second I change all white colors within a tolerance of 30% to black.

Third I perform Otsu thresholding using one of my scripts.

Fourth I do a small amount of morphology close.

Fifth I use connected components processing to remove all regions smaller than 150 pixels in area. In OpenCV, that would be blob detection (SimpleBlobDetection) and invert (negate) the result as a mask.

Last, I put the mask into the alpha channel of the input to make the background transparent (which will show up white here).

```
convert image.jpg -blur 0x1 -colorspace HCL -channel r -separate hue.png
convert hue.png -fuzz 30% -fill black -opaque white filled.png
otsuthresh -g save filled.png thresh.png
convert thresh.png -morphology open disk:1 morph.png
convert morph.png -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=150 \
-connected-components 4 \
-negate \
mask.png
convert image.jpg mask.png -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite result.png
```

Here are the image for the steps:

Hue Image:
[image]

Filled Image after converting white to black:
[image]

Otsu Thresholded Image:
[image]

Mask:
[image]

Result:
[image]

As you can see, the result is not very good at keeping to the outline of the woman and the dress, especially in the hair and the netting of the dress.

You might investigate OpenCV GrabCut Foreground Extaction at https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume the background is fairly simple, (uniform in color, or only nearly horizontal lines) you could do edge detection, and the remove all pixels that's outside the first occuring edge.

Any edge detection filter should be sufficient, But I would probably go for a simple high pass filter, that enhances vertical edges only.
You'r merely trying to figure out where the models silhouette is!

Then remove all the pixels from the frame, going inwards, till the first edge is encountered. (cleans up background outside model).

To remove holes between arms and dress etc.. Median the color value of the removed pixels, to get the background color for this row, then remove pixels with a color value close to the found mean on the remainder of the row.

removals should be done via building a mask image, and then subtract it from the image, as the mask can be used for an opacity / alpha channel afterwards.

risks:

- if dress or model is too close in colour to the background, holes will appear in the model/dress.
- patterns in background disturbs algorithm and leaves rows untouched.
- noise in the background can cause the removal or colour value to be set from pixels close to the frame only.

some of those problems can be minimized by opening and closing the deletion mask.
others by a spacial median filter prior to edge detection.

Answer (score 0):

First step is to calculate the background color(s). Get a block of `50*50` find the variance, shift `10-20 pixels` to right and get another block, calculate its variance as well and many more. Store the variances in an array. (and their means as well).

The ones with lowest variance are background colors, you will see bunch of those. After finding the background color, choose 5*5 blocks and if the variance is very small and its mean is equal to one of the backgrounds (i.e similar characteristic), then make it white or do whatever you want.

That is just my intuition, I'm not professional about image processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try in order to extract dress from image of a model.

1. The [link](https://github.com/fxia22/PixelDTGAN) is github repo of image-conditional image generation model called **PixelDTGAN**. This model will perform a challenging task of generating a piece of clothing from an input image of a dressed person
2. This model transfers an input domain to a target domain in semantic level, and generates the target image in pixel level.
3. To generate realistic target images, the real/fake-discriminator is used as in Generative Adversarial Nets, a domain-discriminator is used to make the generated image relevant to the input image.